# Find an Integer in a List using Tail Recursion in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to simply find an integer in a list using tail recursion in Scala,
An example list: (1,2,3,4)
I want to find a value: 3
I want it to return a boolean, true or false, if it is in the list or not.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: Why you are going for recursion just use `contains`, it will return `true/false`.

Answer (score -4):

```
def findInList(list: List[Int], intToFind: Int): Boolean = {
  findInList(list, 0, intToFind)
}

def findInList(list: List[Int], index: Int, intToFind: Int): Boolean = {
  if(index >= list.length)
    false
  else if(list(index) == inToFind)
    true
  else
    findInList(list, index + 1, intToFind)
}
```

Simply call `def findInList(list: List[Int], intToFind: Int)` and you will get the result.

Comment: Why did someone downvote it ? Well the thing is that `List` in Scala are `LinkedList` so something like `list(index)` on `List` in `Scala` is `O(n)`. Which means you really avaoid multiple `list(index)` calls unless explicitly required.